# How to display stimulus accurately using frames

Tags: psychopy

I have a bit of code attached below that display a stimulus for a certain number of frames.

```
from psychopy import visual, logging, event, core

#create a window to draw in
myWin = visual.Window((600,600), allowGUI=False, blendMode='add', useFBO=True)
logging.console.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

#INITIALISE SOME STIMULI
grating1 = visual.GratingStim(myWin,mask="gauss",
    color=[1.0,1.0,1.0],contrast=0.5,
    size=(1.0,1.0), sf=(4,0), ori = 45,
    autoLog=False)#this stim changes too much for autologging to be useful
grating2 = visual.GratingStim(myWin,mask="gauss",
    color=[1.0,1.0,1.0],opacity=0.5,
    size=(1.0,1.0), sf=(4,0), ori = -45,
    autoLog=False)#this stim changes too much for autologging to be useful

for frameN in range(300):
    grating1.draw()
    grating2.draw()
    win.flip()

myWin.flip()          #update the screen
```

At 60Hz frame refresh rate, 300 frames should be approximately 5 seconds. When I test it out - it is definitely longer then that.

In my experiment, I need the number of frames to be as few as 2 frames - and it seems that my code isn't going to be displaying that accurately.

I was wondering if there is a better way to display the number of frames? Such as using the  `grating1.draw()` and `grating1.draw()` before the for-loop maybe?

I appreciate any help - thanks!

Comment: On laptops things can be tricky. Are you using a laptop? You might also wish to see http://www.psychopy.org/api/visual/window.html which has a section on getting the refresh rate (search for the word refresh on that page). I have occassionally had to flip twice. But I also wonder if the line `win.flip()` is doing what you think. What is `win`? Should it be `myWin`?

Comment: Your script looks right. Drawing outside the loop will only show the stims on first iteration. There are really no optimization options in your case since it's already very efficient. Drawing GratingStims should be really really fast (less than 0.5 ms on most hardware). So try this: (1) run it on a different computer. Is it the same problem? It isn't here, so my guess is that it's specific to your computer. (2) Check that your system frame rate is set to 60 Hz. (2) Try running Coder --> demos --> timing --> timesByFrames. It should give a narrow distribution around 16.667 ms.

Comment: @brittUWaterloo is correct that you are referring to the wrong window in the loop (if `win` even exists), and the final `myWin.flip()` is extraneous. But to give a proper answer, you need to give actual timing values, just around the 300 frame drawing loop. There is a big time cost in the start-up and initialisation period which shouldn't be included in the timing. Give actual timing results, and conduct the tests as @Jonas Lindeløv suggests, and update the question.

Answer (score 0):

The timing discrepancy might be due to the frame rate not being exactly 60Hz. Try using myWin.getActualFrameRate() ([PsychoPy documentation](http://www.psychopy.org/api/visual/window.html#psychopy.visual.Window.getActualFrameRate)) to get the actual frame rate. Multiplying the real frame rate by 5.0 seconds should theoretically allow you to draw for exactly 5.0 seconds.

```
frame_rate = myWin.getActualFrameRate(nIdentical=60, nMaxFrames=100,
    nWarmUpFrames=10, threshold=1)

# The number of frames you want to display is equal to
# the product of frame-rate and the number of seconds to display
# the stimulus.
# n_frames = frame_rate * n_seconds

for frameN in range(frame_rate*5.0):
    grating1.draw()
    grating2.draw()
    myWin.flip()
```